# Using Try Catch to find Boolean value

Tags: c#, boolean, try-catch

I have several bool checks against values. I wanted to check in ANY of the values return false then do something.

I attempted the follow:

```
bool formIsValid = true;

try{

    Utility.testStringHasValue(txEmail.Text);   <--- true
    Utility.testStringHasValue(txFirstName.Text);  <--- true
    Utility.testStringHasValue(txLastName.Text);  <--- FALSE
    Utility.testStringHasValue(txUserEmployer.Text); <--- true
    Utility.testStringHasValue(txUserPassword.Text); <--- true
    Utility.testStringHasValue(txUserPassword2.Text); <--- true
}
catch (Exception)
{
    formIsValid = false
}
```

.. any other solutions as this one does not at all!

**UPDATE**

I removed the Try/Catch completely and used:

```
bool isFormValid = Utility.testStringHasValue(txEmail.Text)
                && Utility.testStringHasValue(txFirstName.Text)
                && Utility.testStringHasValue(txLastName.Text)
                && Utility.testStringHasValue(txUserEmployer.Text)
                && Utility.testStringHasValue(txUserPassword.Text)
                && Utility.testStringHasValue(txUserPassword2.Text)
                && (txUserPassword.Text == txUserPassword2.Text);
```

Comment: Not a great case for exception handling.

Comment: What is `Utility.testStringHasValue`?

Comment: The try/catch here basically acts as an unlabeled goto :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wrote the Utility methods, then I would suggest making sure it won't throw an exception, especially if it returns a boolean indicating whether the string has a value.

You could just do the following, and avoid the `try { } catch { }` entirely.

```
bool formIsValid = Utility.testStringHasValue(txEmail.Text);   <--- true
                   && Utility.testStringHasValue(txFirstName.Text);  <--- true
                   && Utility.testStringHasValue(txLastName.Text);  <--- FALSE
                   && Utility.testStringHasValue(txUserEmployer.Text); <--- true
                   && Utility.testStringHasValue(txUserPassword.Text); <--- true
                   && Utility.testStringHasValue(txUserPassword2.Text); <--- true
```

`&&` will not call evaluate the right side unless the left side returns `true`, so `Utility.testStringHasValue` will only actually be called 3 times in your example.

Answer (score 4):

Dont use exceptions for that scenario, when an exception is thrown there is a performance hit.

There is also a method available already to check if a string is entered ( String.IsNullOrEmpty )

You could use the **&&** (and) operator to validate all fields are valid.

eg:

```
bool isValid = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEmail.Text) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFirstname.Text) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLastName.Text);
```

Alternatively, you could flip it the other way using the **||** (or) operator

```
bool isInvalid = String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEmail.Text) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFirstname.Text) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLastName.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( Utility.testStringHasValue(txEmail.Text) &&
     Utility.testStringHasValue(txFirstName.Text) &&
     Utility.testStringHasValue(txLastName.Text) &&
     Utility.testStringHasValue(txUserEmployer.Text) &&
     Utility.testStringHasValue(txUserPassword.Text) &&
     Utility.testStringHasValue(txUserPassword2.Text)
) { 
  all_good = true;
} else {
  no_so_good = true;
}
```

Exception handling should not be used as control logic. It obfuscates the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

That's because returning `false` doesn't throw an exception.  You could always do:

```
if (!(
    Utility.testStringHasValue(txEmail.Text) &&
    Utility.testStringHasValue(txFirstName.Text) &&
    Utility.testStringHasValue(txLastName.Text) &&
    Utility.testStringHasValue(txUserEmployer.Text) &&
    Utility.testStringHasValue(txUserPassword.Text) &&
    Utility.testStringHasValue(txUserPassword2.Text)))
{
    throw new Exception("Something is false");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( !(condtion1 && condition2 && .... && conditionN) )
{
  // first condition evaluating to false gets you here
  // anything afterwards is not checked.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recode your `Utility.testStringHasValue()` to return false, not throw an exception.
Next

```
formIsValid= Utility.testStringHasValue(txEmail.Text) &&
    Utility.testStringHasValue(txFirstName.Text) &&
    Utility.testStringHasValue(txLastName.Text) && 
    Utility.testStringHasValue(txUserEmployer.Text) &&
    Utility.testStringHasValue(txUserPassword.Text) &&
    Utility.testStringHasValue(txUserPassword2.Text) ;

if (formIsValid) {
    //whatever
} else {
    //whatever
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What does testStringHasValue return? if a boolean then just use all the combined return values instead, like this :

```
boolean result = true;
result = result && Utility.testStringHasValue(txEmail.Text); 
result = result && Utility.testStringHasValue(txFirstName.Text);
return result;
```

The way you are using exceptions is not very good. They should not be used for this kind of validation and your intention to reach the catch will only be valid if you actuelly throw a exception not onyl because it returns a boolean false value.

Answer (score 0):

try..catch exception handling is more expensive than a simple boolean check, resource-wise.  From the msdn site re: try..catch: "Catching exceptions at runtime creates additional overhead, and is likely to be slower than pre-checking to avoid exceptions."
Use if..then as shown previously.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about writing a reusable method to check all the values passed to it aren't empty?  Something like this could be a major time saver if you are using the code in multiple places:

```
using System.Linq;

public static class Utility
{
    public static bool EnsureValuesNotEmpty(params string[] values)
    {
        return values.All(value => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value));
    }
}
```

Then you can re-use the functionality with a lot less code, just pass all the values you want to check to it:

```
var formIsValid = Utility.EnsureValuesNotEmpty(txEmail.Text,
                                               txFirstName.Text,
                                               txLastName.Text,
                                               txUserEmployer.Text,
                                               txUserPassword.Text,
                                               txUserPassword2.Text);
```